# Getting postfix working? Getting error: "Recipient address rejected: Policy Rejection- Please try later.;"

Tags: centos, postfix

I'm running on Rackspace Cloud Servers and I've just setup a CentOS build and installed iRedMail. The problem is, 90% of the email I'm sending gets blocked and I get the error in my maillog:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[209.85.222.185]: 450 4.7.1 <user@domain.com>:
Recipient address rejected: Policy Rejection- Please try later.; 
from=<user@domain2.com> to=<user@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo='<mail-pz0-f185.google.com>
```

For spam reasons I've taken out the real emails and put in pseudo ones.

I asked the technical support for some help and it wasn't much help. I've setup the SPF and TXT records but still no luck.

Any tips on what I could try or what I should look at or is this a ridiculous too open a question with too many things that could cause the issue?

Any help would really be appreciated. This is my first time setting up postfix from scratch :|

**edit: somebody just told me that the emails are being 'greylisted' by my postfix setup to avoid being spammed.**

Comment: just thought I'd add - the emails do seem to eventually come through... is that weird? so they are being stopped for some reason, then sent later through dovecot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mention SPF and TXT records, but forward and reverse DNS need to be correct as well.

edit: easiest way I know to test:

```
dig -x +short `dig +short your.domain.com`
```

This should return "your.domain.com". If it does not, then separate the two commands:

```
dig your.domain.com
dig -x your.ip.address
```

to see which or both is not working correctly.

Comment: thanks for that. would you mind elaborating? how do I check if they are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Simply white list that domain like 
cd to /opt/iredapd/tools

```
Whitelist IP networks/addresses specified in sender domain:
python greylisting_admin.py --whitelist-domain --from '@example.com'
```

Find more information from the [documentation](http://www.iredmail.org/docs/manage.iredapd.html)